# Elegant way to view JSONEncode() output in swift

Tags: json, swift, encoding, jsonencoder

```
var test = [String : String] ()
test["title"] = "title"
test["description"] = "description"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
let json = try? encoder.encode(test)
```

How can I see the output of the `json`?

If I use `print(json)` the only thing I get is `Optional(45 bytes)`

Answer (score 37, accepted):

The `encode()` method returns `Data` containing the JSON representation  in UTF-8 encoding. So you can just convert it back to a string:

```
var test = [String : String] ()
test["title"] = "title"
test["description"] = "description"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let json = try? encoder.encode(test) {
    print(String(data: json, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

Output:

```
{"title":"title","description":"description"}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , can you tell me what's the difference between `JSONEncoder` and `JSSONSerilization` ?

Comment: @Amir: JSONEncoder/JSONDecoder are new in Swift 4 and – roughly speaking – allow the encoding/decoding of custom data structures. See https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0166-swift-archival-serialization.md for the details. See also the "Swift 4" part in https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/swift/223/reading-writing-json#t=201707101855392281446.

Comment: Nice one! Thx :)

Answer (score 6):

With Swift 4, `String` has a initializer called `init(data:encoding:)`. `init(data:encoding:)` has the following declaration:

```
init?(data: Data, encoding: String.Encoding)
```

> Returns a `String` initialized by converting given `data` into Unicode characters using a given `encoding`.

---

The following Playground snippets show how to use `String` `init(data:encoding:)` initializer in order to print a JSON data content:

```
import Foundation

var test = [String : String]()
test["title"] = "title"
test["description"] = "description"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
if let data = try? encoder.encode(test),
    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {"title":"title","description":"description"}
 */
```

Alternative using `JSONEncoder.OutputFormatting` set to `prettyPrinted`:

```
import Foundation

var test = [String : String]()
test["title"] = "title"
test["description"] = "description"

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted

if let data = try? encoder.encode(test),
    let jsonString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
    print(jsonString)
}

/*
 prints:
 {
   "title" : "title",
   "description" : "description"
 }
 */
```

Comment: Now how do we append more items to the same json?